# Rails Nested attributes with check_box loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

So I have a categories model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :provider_categories
has_many :providers, :through => :provider_categories
end
```

and a provider model

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :provider_categories
has_many :categories, :through => :provider_categories

accepts_nested_attributes_for :provider_categories, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

here is my provider_category model

```
class ProviderCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :provider
belongs_to :category
end
```

I'm trying to create a nested form to include the categories into the provider form

```
= form_for @provider do |f|
  ...
  -@categories.each.with_index do |category,index|
    =f.fields_for :provider_category, category do |pl|
      =pl.check_box :category_id
      =pl.label category.name
      =pl.hidden_field :provider_id, value: @provider.id
```

The checkbox is not cooperating when I load the page I get

```
undefined method `category_id' for #<Category:0x0000010184ff60>
```

**EDIT:**

if I change the :category_id to id it works but the html outpuy looks like this

```
<input name="provider[provider_category][id]" type="hidden" value="0"><input checked="checked" id="provider_provider_category_id" name="provider[provider_category][id]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="provider_provider_category_Acupuncture">Acupuncture</label>
<input id="provider_provider_category_provider_id" name="provider[provider_category][provider_id]" type="hidden" value="1">
```

**EDIT 2:**

I ended up using check_box_tag

```
-@categories.each.with_index do |category|
  =f.fields_for :provider_category, category do |pl|
    .li
      =check_box_tag "provider[provider_category][category_id]", category.id
      =pl.label category.name
      =pl.hidden_field :provider_id, value: @provider.id
```

Now the html output seems to be correct but it's not saving it. When I select multiple items this is the hash from saving

```
"provider"=>{"name"=>"Mr. Awesome", "phone"=>"999-999-9999", "email"=>"awesome@awesome.com", "address"=>"awesome land", "provider_category"=>{"category_id"=>"3", "provider_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
```

I did select 3 options but only the last one was added to the hash

I also added the provider categories in the strong params of provider controller

```
params.require(:provider).permit(..., :provider_categories => [:category_id, :provider_id])
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS per your model definitions, `ProviderCategory` has attributes `category_id` and `provider_id`. You are getting error as:

```
undefined method `category_id' for #<Category:0x0000010184ff60>
```

because instead of passing instance of `ProviderCategory`, you have passed an instance of `Category` class. Notice `category` being passed in

```
=f.fields_for :provider_category, category do |pl|
```

and as there is no attribute named `category_id` in model `Category` you receive the error.

To resolve that, just update the `fields_for` method call in your view as below:

```
=f.fields_for :provider_categories, category.provider_categories.build do |pl|
```

**UPDATE**

Also, you would have to update the strong params of `ProvidersController` so that records for  `provider_categories` are saved correctly in database:

```
params.require(:provider).permit(..., :provider_categories_attributes => [:category_id, :provider_id])
```

Use `provider_categories_attributes` and not `provider_categories`

**UPDATE 2**

OP had another problem, for the unchecked `category_id`, value `0` was being passed and incorrect records with `category_id` set as `0` were getting created in `provider_categories`.

Suggested to reject those records by passing `reject_if` option to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method call in `Provider` model as below:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provider_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :provider_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :provider_categories, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['category_id'] == "0" }
end
```

Checkbox was not passing the id's of checked categories, suggested to update the checkbox code as below:

```
=pl.check_box :category_id, {}, category.id, 0
```

Comment: I still get the same error I ended up using check_box_tag "provider[provider_category][category_id]", category.id

Comment: `check_box_tag` is an alternative. BUT your current code with little modification as suggested should have worked. I wonder why you get the same error. If you want and are curious to know we could debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror