# Create multiple new records from checkboxes in form using nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nested-attributes

I'm trying to come up with a contact form that creates a contact record and potentially multiple location records, if multiple locations are checked in a list of checkboxes. I thought of having all location records created and then destroyed, if they aren't checked. I don't think that's optimal though.

I'm using many to many relationships in the models.

This is what they look like at the moment:

contact.rb

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
has_many :contact_locations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :locations, through: :contact_locations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_locations, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :empty_location?

private
def empty_location?(att)

att['location_id'].blank?

end

end
```

location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :contacts, :through => :contact_locations
has_many :contact_locations
end
```

contact_location.rb

```
class ContactLocation < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :contact
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
def new
@contact = Contact.new
@locations = Location.all
4.times {@contact.contact_locations.new}
end

private

def contact_params
params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone, ..., contact_locations_attributes: [:location_ids])
end
```

new.html.rb

```
<%= form_with model: @contact do |f| %>
  ...
<%= @locations.each do |location| %>
<%= f.fields_for :contact_locations do |l| %>
<%= l.check_box :location_id, {}, location.id, nil %><%= l.label location.name %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Does anyone how to make it work properly?
I'm working on Ruby 2.5.1 and Rails 5.2.1.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making it work with Kirti's suggestion on the following question:
[Rails Nested attributes with check_box loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419607/rails-nested-attributes-with-check-box-loop)

It turns out I needed to make a small adjustment in my form's fields_for tag.

Thanks a lot the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the form objects pattern.

You can have something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.fields_for @user.build_location do |g| %>
    <%= g.text_field :country %>
  <% end %>
<% end%>
```

And convert it in something more readable that permits you to instance the locations inside the registration object, checking the value of the checkboxes.

```
<%= form_for @registration do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>

  <%= f.input :country %>
  <%= f.text_field :country %>

  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>

  <%= f.button :submit, 'Create account' %>
<% end %>
```

Here you will find how to apply the pattern: https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/saving-multiple-models-with-form-objects-and-transactions-2c26f37f7b9a